# Visual Studio not able to access OpenXml SDK 2.5

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio, sdk

```
Imports DocumentsFormat.OperXml.Packageing
Imports DocumentsFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing
```

Build complains about "Imports" statement is unnecessary.

NameSpace or type in the imports ... doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found."

The installed resource can't be located.

I've attempted to look through the bells & whistles of Visual Studio (which I'm new to) but can't locate anything to fix to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

For those, like me, who are new to the Microsoft side of computing and are not familiar with VS 2019.

Solution Explorer can be located under the View tab.
View -> Solution Explorer and your current project will be displayed. If you click on Packages you'll see collected, in one section, the dlls or files that's being used by your project.

To include packages you want to include in your project go to Projects -> Manage NuGetPackages you can see a list of packages avliable. Click there to install.